# Force fresh content, not from the browser cache

Tags: htaccess, browsers, optimization

I used the following code in the htaccess to put my site under maintenance and show the visitors maintenance.html.

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$
 RewriteRule $ /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

My site is now back online but now I see that all those browsers that tried to go on my site during the maintenance, they are still getting the maintenance.html.

It works if I clear the browser cache and I sort of understand why it is happening. I think the browser caches the redirect and is still doing it.

How can I clear this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should force your users back to the main site - you can use a meta refresh redirect or a htaccess redirect.

You can use this in the Maintenance html - includes a delay of 3 seconds, you could add to the page - the site is back online you are being redirected to the main site.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL='http://www.yourdomain.com/'">
```

Htaccess Method

```
Redirect 301 /maintenance.html http://www.yourdomain.com/
```

Comment: If the original `.htaccess` redirect for maintenance is cached, won't this cause some sort of infinite loop?

Comment: You can change the name of the maintenance URL to force a refresh.